# SAS rename when column name is date

Tags: date, sas, rename

I need to start from sas data have and get sas data want. Below is the test dataset. My actual data has much more date column so I cannot rename them manually. The first two columns (not date columns) do not have to be renamed. For the first date column, rename it as V1, second V2, and there after V3, V4. ...

```
Data have;
Name= "John";
City="ice";
'06/2006'n= 23;
'07/2006'n = 56;
'12/2006'n = 43;
'11/2006'n = 23;
'10/2006'n = 12;
Run;

Data want;
Name= "John";
City="ice";
V1= 23;
V2 = 56;
V3= 43;
V4 = 23;
V5= 12;
Run;
```

Code included in comments

```
%macro rename(lib,dsn); 
proc sql noprint; 
select nvar into :num_vars 
from dictionary.tables 
where libname="&LIB" 
and memname="&DSN"; 

select distinct(name) into :var1- :var%TRIM(%LEFT(&num_vars)) 
from dictionary.columns 
where libname="&LIB" 
and memname="&DSN"; 
quit;run; 

proc datasets library=&LIB; 
    modify &DSN; 
    rename %do i=1 %to &num_vars; 
                &&var&i=V&i. 
            %end;; 
quit; run; 
%mend rename; 

%rename(WORK,ONE);
```

Comment: The code below works if the column name is not date and if I start from the third column, I can only get V3=23 instead of getting V1=23.

    %macro rename(lib,dsn);
    proc sql noprint; select nvar into :num_vars
    from dictionary.tables  where libname="&LIB" and
    memname="&DSN";
    select distinct(name) into :var1-
    :var%TRIM(%LEFT(&num_vars))
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname="&LIB" and
    memname="&DSN"; quit;run;
proc datasets library=&LIB;
modify &DSN;
rename
%do i=1 %to &num_vars;
&&var&i=V&i.
%end;;
    quit;
    run;

    %mend rename;
    %rename(WORK,ONE);

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code in the question, not in comments. I've moved it for you here.

Answer (score 0):

Clunky but functional:

```
proc sql;
    create table vars as select 
        name
        from dictionary.columns
        where memname = upcase("have");
quit;

data vars2;
    set vars;
    if (_n_ - 2) > 0 then do;
        new_name = "V"||strip(_n_ - 2);
    end;
    else do;
        new_name = name;
    end;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    select name into: old_names
    separated by "|"
    from vars2;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
    select new_name into: new_names
    separated by "|"
    from vars2;
quit;

%macro renamer;
    data want;
        set have;
        %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&old_names.));
            rename %scan(&old_names., &i., "|") = %scan(&new_names., &i., "|");
        %end;
    run;
%mend renamer;

%renamer;
```

Comment: I cannot run the last macro piece. When scan , 06/2006 will be read as 06, and for the next iteration it will read in 2006. The code breaks here.

Comment: If you just use another delimiter instead of " " this should be okay; see edit

Answer (score 0):

Your macro is close, but has too many things included and a bunch of errors.

1. You can use varnum column to select column names that aren't the first 2
2. You don't need to count the number of vars - there's an automatic macro variable `SQLOBS` that gets created that holds the number.
3. Your rename statement needs another `&` to resolve properly.
4. You need to account for the quotes required in the varname - it needs to resolve to '01/2006'n.

**5. You may be able to avoid all of the above by setting `options validvarname=v7` before you import this dataset. You should also store data like this in long form rather than a wide format. It may also be easier to transpose and rename, then re-transpose again.  I'll leave that solution to someone else.**

There are a bunch of smaller things, but I'll leave it to you to examine the code. The code below works for me.

```
%macro rename(lib,dsn); 
proc sql;
select distinct(catt(quote(trim(name)), 'n')) into :var1- 
from dictionary.columns 
where libname=upper("&LIB") 
and memname=upper("&DSN")
and varnum > 2; 
quit;

%let num_vars = &sqlobs;

proc datasets library=&LIB; 
    modify &DSN; 
    rename %do i=1 %to &num_vars; 
                &&&var&i=V&i. 
            %end;; 
run; quit;
%mend rename; 

%rename(WORK,have);
```

EDIT: Using NLITERAL function instead as suggested:

```
%macro rename(lib,dsn); 
proc sql;
select distinct(nliteral(name)) into :var1- 
from dictionary.columns 
where libname=upper("&LIB") 
and memname=upper("&DSN")
and varnum > 2; 
quit;

%let num_vars = &sqlobs;

proc datasets library=&LIB; 
    modify &DSN; 
    rename %do i=1 %to &num_vars; 
                &&&var&i=V&i. 
            %end;; 
run; quit;
%mend rename; 

%rename(WORK,have);
```

Comment: See function NLITERAL to fix this catt(quote(trim(name)), 'n')).  I has the advantage of only adding quote and n when the variable needs to be expressed and an name literal

Comment: Don't use `UPPER` function (or any functions) in the WHERE clause when querying DICTIONARY tables as it will cause SAS to query the metadata for all tables instead of using the index. In this case you can use the macro function  `%UPCASE()` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a beginner and will try to revise my code based on your advice. Very useful comments for me.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't need to rename thousands of variables you can do the code generation with just one macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
  %let rename=;
  select catx('=',nliteral(name),cats('V',varnum-2))
    into :rename separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname='WORK' and memname='HAVE'
      and not findw('Name City',name,' ','sir')
  ;
quit;
data want ;
  set have (rename=(&rename)) ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you, you code works, but could you please explain why you have the statement :   and not findw('Name City',name,' ','sir'). Why Name City are in the same quote, where is the name "" 'sir' from?

Comment: Excludes the records for variables name and city.  When the word contained in the variable NAME exists in the space delimited list 'NAME CITY' .  The 'i' means to ignore case.  The 'r' says to trim delimiters from the value of NAME.